# overloading operator outside of struct

Tags: c++, struct, set, operator-overloading

I have a `struct` and would like to implement a `set` of its pointers. So I try to overload `operator <` to make it happen. One limitation here is that I do not have access to write overloading code within the struct definition. How can I do it outside of the struct?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct mystruct {
    int label;
    vector<mystruct *> neighbors;
};
bool operator < (mystruct * n1, mystruct* n2) {
    return n1 -> label < n2 -> label;
};
int main() {
    set<mystruct *> s;
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is

> error: overloaded 'operator<' must have at least one parameter of
>   class or enumeration type

Comment: Wh do you need pointers in your set? You can't overload intrinsic operators.

Comment: Let's pretend the struct part cannot be edited.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I mean I am not allowed to define operator < in the struct scope.

Comment: But why do you need pointers in the set? You can't overload the definition of the `operator<()` for pointers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I changed the question into "implement a set of its pointers". And if it is set<mystruct>, the code works.

Comment: `int main() { set<mystruct *> s; {mystruct m; s.insert(&m);} return 0;}`  I have just broken your `set`, since it now has a bogus pointer as an element.  That's why you're being asked why you need a set of pointers.

Comment: _"And if it is set<mystruct>, the code works."_ Sure. Why did you think of pointers in 1st place? What's the problem (use case) you want to solve?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Good question. I am actually dealing with a problem related to graph. Structs have neighbors. I edited the code again with one more detail. Now struct has a vector of pointers, which is given by the problem.

Comment: @YiBao I'm not so sure if `std::set` is the correct data structure to solve your original problem.

Comment: Keen observation. It turns out `std::set` is not a good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with

```
bool operator < (mystruct * n1, mystruct* n2) {
    return n1 -> label < n2 -> label;
};
```

Is that both `n1` and `n2` are pointers.  Even though they are pointers to `mystruct` they are still just pointers and you cannot overload operators for pointers as they are built in.  The simplest way to fix this is to take references instead and work with values like

```
bool operator < (const mystruct& n1, const mystruct7 n2) {
    return n.label < n2.label;
};

int main() {
    set<mystruct> s;
    return 0;
}
```

If you can't do that then you need to provide a comparison functor to the `std::set` and have it use that function instead of `operator <`.  That would look like

```
struct mystruct_pointer_comp
{
    bool operator ()(mystruct * n1, mystruct* n2) {
        return n1->label < n2->label;
    };
}

int main() {
    set<mystruct *, mystruct_pointer_comp> s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An intermediate solution (if you don't want to give ownership of the objects to the container) could be to create the "regular" overload with references, and use a `std::set<std::reference_wrapper<mystruct>>`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Not sure how well that would work since the objects the wrapper wraps will need to exist outside the set and for as long as the set exists.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Most probably more something like a `std::set<std::unique_ptr<mystruct>>` then. But it's questionable why to use a `std::set` then at all.